# MySQL disregard where condition if value is null or empty

Tags: mysql

I'm making an API for our search with filter.
My problem is I don't want to make many query for it for the filter condition,
so my question is can I disregard a where condition if the value is null or empty in SQL?

sample:

```
where name = "if ( empty disregard this condition )" 
  AND status = "if ( empty disregard this condition )"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with these `CASE` expressions:

```
where
  1 = case when coalesce(trim(?), '') = '' then 1 else (name = ?) end
  and
  1 = case when coalesce(trim(?), '') = '' then 1 else (status = ?) end
```

replace the `?` placeholders with the actual values that you pass.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=cd35ef922715e17d8da15035c2a81dea).

Answer (score 0):

Use `IS NOT NULL` for NULL values and essentially not equal (`<>`) to blank for empty.

`SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE value IS NOT NULL AND value <>''`

Comment: it works but the condition that I want is like

`where name = "if ( empty disregard this condition )" AND status = "if ( empty disregard this condition )"`

Answer (score 0):

use `IF(field_name IS NULL, 0, 1)`. Second and Third parameter is `true` and `false` condition respectively.